# What does the sum notation $\sum\limits_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

> What does the sum notation $\sum\limits_{j=n}^\infty a_j$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, mean?

Is this the sequence of the sums, i.e:

$$ \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j=\left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j,\;
  \sum_{j=2}^\infty a_j,\;
  \sum_{j=3}^\infty a_j,\;
  \sum_{j=4}^\infty a_j,\;
  \sum_{j=5}^\infty a_j,\;
   \ldots\right)\ ?
$$

Comment: @Antitheos if $n$ is a fixed number in $\mathbb N$ then it means the limit of the partial sums. But if it is for all $n\in\mathbb N$ then it is the sequence that mavavilj wrote. I.e it is the sequence of limits of partial sums.

Comment: Good point, I'll delete.

Comment: Following an expression by a comma and then "$n\in\mathbb N$" is the same as writing "where $n$ is a natural number". It does not denote a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the limit of the partial sums when $k\rightarrow \infty$ and $n\in\mathbb N$ is fixed, i.e $$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{j=n}^{k}{a_j}$$
If it was $$\left\{\sum\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}{a_j}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$ then it is the sequence that you wrote.

Comment: Can you write that open? As a sequence or series.

Answer (score -1):

Basically the notation
$$\sum\limits_{j=n}^\infty a_j$$ is the infinite sum of the values of $a_j$ when $j$ changes so:
$$
\sum\limits_{j=n}^\infty a_j=a_n+a_{n+1}++a_{n+2}+a_{n+3}+a_{n+4}+ \cdots
$$ up until $n$ reaches infinity.